# How to convert from java.sql.Date to ZonedDateTime

Tags: mysql, spring, zoneddatetime

I am trying to convert from java.sql.Date to ZonedDateTime. This is the code I am using

```
ZonedDateTime.from(new java.util.Date(result.get(0).getTime()).toInstant())
```

However, it leads to the following error -

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2016-09-29T18:30:00Z of type java.time.Instant
```

Is there a way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime zdt =
    myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate()
                 .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

## Details

Do not mix the old date-time classes with java.time. Avoid the old classes. So your call to `java.util.Date` is not helpful.

Know that `java.sql.Date` represents a date-only value, with no time-of-day and no time zone. Unfortunately it actually does have a time-of-day and a time zone, but we are supposed to ignore those facts. This is a poorly-designed hack of a class. Use it only when you do not yet have a JDBC driver that supports JDBC 4.2 and the java.time types.

So when you must use `java.sql.Date` convert its value to a `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

To convert to/from java.time, look to new methods added to the old classes.

```
LocalDate ld = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

Going the other direction.

```
java.sql.Date myJavaSqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( ld );
```

If your goal is getting a date-time value from a date-only value, you will need to specify a time-of-day. If you want the first moment of the day, let java.time determine that time-of-day for you. The time `00:00:00` is *not* always the start of the day because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). Handling such anomalies requires you to specify a time zone as each zone has its own rules for its own anomalies. So apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: While it's very right that those should not be mixed, do notice that the poster is using spring. I arrived here because I probably have the same issue they are having: when the result of a query method is `datetime` instead of an entity, spring-data in some cases converts it _only_ to `java.sql.Date`, even though hibernate allows for persisting entities with ZonedDateTime fields. In this case, we are not mixing them because we want to, but because we have absolutely no other choice short of making a query that returns an entity instead, or abandoning spring-data altogether.

Answer (score 2):

All you can do is change to local date time with time set to start of the day since java sql date doesn't have time component. Use timezone or default to system time zone to get zoned date time

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(result.get(0).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```